# как обратится к обычному классу внутри css module?

Tags: css, reactjs, scss

```
//внутри модуля
.my{
    //обычный класс из какой-то библиотеки
    .any{

    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules#exceptions

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно использовать псевдокласс :global, в твоем случае код будет выглядить так

```
//внутри модуля
.my{
    //обычный класс из какой-то библиотеки
    :global(.any) {

    }
}
```

Comment: интерестный вариант, но лутше писать не как аргумент, а в теле :gloabal

Comment: не всегда, если нужно перебить библиотечный стиль, то нужно дабавить вес классу, лучше всего сделать это сделать более уникальный селектор

Comment: то есть вес у такого варианта больше, чем в теле :gloabal?